# Analyzing 4-pin data port to determine protocol

Tags: reverse-engineering, logic-analyzer

I have a Solar controller for my pool, it controls the pump and actuator for routing water onto the roof to heat it up, when required. The controller knows the pool and roof temperatures, as well as the state of the pump and actuator. All of which I'd like to monitor.

The controller has a 4-pin port labelled "Data". I would like to interface to this port to monitor the controller and pool parameters, if possible. I contacted the manufacturer but they responded with a generic "this port isn't supported for end users" kind of thing, as I expected they would. I have searched around, of course, but nobody has documented this port.

I would like to determine if this 4-pin data port speaks a standard protocol that I could potentially connect to.
[image: Solar Controller Ports]
This "Data" port has 4 pins labelled: "BK", "W", "R", "BL". (See photo)

I assume these labels are abbreviations for Black, White, Red, Blue.

Based on that, I've made an assumption that "BK" is Ground.

With a multimeter I have probed pairs of pins to determine:

```
BK <-> W     +5V
BK <-> R     0V
BK <-> BL    +5V
```

I borrowed a Saleae Logic Analyzer from a friend and wired up its probes to analyze the port output. Again, assuming BK was Ground. The analysis revealed chatter on the W pin, although all the other pins revealed no activity. See the two screen shots below, one showing the full analysis (i.e. zoomed out) and the other showing the zoomed in detail of one of the spikes.

[image: Saleae Analysis Zoomed out]
[image: Saleae Analysis Zoomed in]

Saleae Logic has a bunch of protocol analyzers built in, and I tried the ones that makes sense with these set of pins, but haven't been able to make any useful sense out of any of them.

I was wondering if this port could simply be a USB port. The latest Logic contains a USB 1.1 analyzer, but it did not recognise anything useful from the probe.

Any suggestions on what kind of port it could be or recommended steps to continue the reverse engineering process would be great.

Comment: Looks way too slow for USB. Starts off looking a bit like async serial but some of the timing doesn't add up.

Comment: Any manufacturer or model no. on that thing? Also check resistance between Bk and earth, e.g. case. It is also possible it needs some input (clock or 5V) on R to talk.

Comment: The controller is one of these http://sunloverheating.com.au/products/controller/. The model number is visible in the photo. There is very little technical info available. I am avoiding opening the unit for now, while under warranty.

Answer (score 4):

It is far too slow to be USB.  Also, USB is differential and this does not appear to be.  It looks a lot like some sort of serial protocol.  Presuming BK is ground, then it would make sense if W is transmit, R is receive, and BL is +5V power.

It definitely looks similar to a standard UART serial signal with a baud rate of between 6000 and 8000 bits per second.  I would suggest playing around with the UART decoder settings, especially number of bits and number of parity/stop bits.  Some of those pulses look pretty narrow, though - I'm not sure what to make of that.

Have you tried looking at the signal with an oscilloscope?  It would be beneficial to confirm the signal levels.

Also, can you take the top off and try to figure out what is in there that those pins might be connected to?  That may provide some insight into what sort of a signal that might be.

Comment: UART make sense, thanks. I have explored UART a little, but haven't been able to find a baud rate or combination of parameters that fit. I will dig further.

Comment: I don't have access to an oscilloscope right now. I'm not sure if opening the unit is practical yet, due to warranty issues. If I can get further information from either of those sources, I'll update the question.